# Redirect from http to https results in redirect loop

Tags: https, url-rewriting, iis-7

I want to redirect all hostnames on my site to https.
I have added following rule in urlRewrite of IIS:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
    redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

But on browsing I am getting redirect loop. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have checked in my local and the rule added above is working fine in my case.

Comment: I see this problem too, but only rarely. I don't know how to reproduce it. Something very strange is going on. Also seems to be a problem in IIS 8, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710470/iis-8-redirect-http-to-https-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is correct. The only issue I can see is the unclosed `<rule>` tag.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```