# IIS 8 redirect HTTP to HTTPS - infinite loop

Tags: redirect, iis

I'm trying to redirect all `http://` requests to `https://` for a **specific site** on IIS 8 (not the whole server). I've tried the instructions in method 1 from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx), [this article](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/redirect_http_to_https_iis_7l) (referenced by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605311/1672458)), and [this webmasters.SE answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28069), but every single one causes an infinite redirect loop.

What's happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: I see it too in IIS 7.5, but only rarely. I don't know how to reproduce it. It sure seems like an IIS bug the more I look at it.